# 'feel interesting vs feel interested'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I encountered the sentence bleow in a speech.

[Please watch at 1:22 and you can see the sentence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRl5re5krBs)

> The speaker said : I think part of fashion is just finding what that balance is for you and what's going to make you feel comfortable and ***interesting*** when you walk down the street

Is 'interesting' connected to 'comfortable'?

If so, does it mean 'what will make you feel comfortable and feel interesting'?

And there's another question. Do you use 'I feel interesting'?

Well sometimes people use 'I am interesting' to say I am kind of a person who interest people.

Is it proper to say 'feel' instead of 'be'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make someone feel comfortable and to make someone feel interesting.
**No, a person would probably not say**: I feel interesting. But they might think it.  And **someone else might say about you**: if you wear this, it will make you feel interestin.

Of course, if you feel interesting, that might be something you "secretly" find enjoyable but you would have to be someone like Donald Duck [ha ha] to actually say it.

If you feel like you are a boring person, perhaps if you felt interesting (without actually saying it to others), you would feel better.

I feel he is an interesting person. That is what is expressed here with "feel interesting". When you feel interesting, you might attract others. If you feel boring, you might not.

Comment: I quite agree that native speakers wouldn't normally say *I feel interesting.* But even though they might *sometimes* say it, there's also a semantic/syntactic disjunct between ***comfortable*** (internal state) and ***interesting*** (external appearance). I don't think those two sit well together.

Comment: A commentator on fashion can easily say that some type of clothing makes a person feel comfortable, feel  interesting, feel free or feel whatever. Feel interesting can be an internal state. Do you feel interesting? (Do you feel like you are an interesting person). How is that external, necessarily? Not sure I agree that there's a disjunction here.

Comment: I think there's a significant difference between *I feel/think I am an interesting person* (perfectly normal, and could even occur as a conversation opening) and *I feel [I am] interesting* (slightly weird unless responding to the suggestion that you might be *boring*, for example). But if you don't see things that way I doubt there's anything I could say that would make any difference. What feels "natural" is the eventual net effect of years or decades of exposure to actual usages, not reasoned debate & discussion.

Comment: The speaker in the text is not an I. It is a fashionista discussing how people feel when wearing clothes: the people feel stupid, smart, interesting. If you feel interesting, it is obviously an internal state. If you feel you are interesting, that means you think are the subject of interest to others. So the opposition is: to feel x versus to feel that [person or pronoun] IS/are x. Not the same thing.

Comment: The question was about "'(feel) interesting vs (feel) interested'. How did this answer address the "interested" part of the question?